# How to convert large UTF-8 encoded char* string to CStringW (UTF-16)?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, mfc

I have a problem with converting a UTF-8 encoded string to a UTF-16 encoded `CStringW`.

Here is my source code:

```
CStringW ConvertUTF8ToUTF16( __in const CHAR * pszTextUTF8 )
{
    _wsetlocale( LC_ALL, L"Korean" );
    if ( (pszTextUTF8 == NULL) || (*pszTextUTF8 == '\0') )
    {
        return L"";
    }
    const size_t cchUTF8Max = INT_MAX - 1;
    size_t cchUTF8;
    HRESULT hr = ::StringCbLengthA( pszTextUTF8, cchUTF8Max, &cchUTF8 );
    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        AtlThrow( hr );
    }
    ++cchUTF8;
    int cbUTF8 = static_cast<int>( cchUTF8 );

    int cchUTF16 = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,
        MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
        pszTextUTF8,
        -1,
        NULL,
        0
        );

    CString strUTF16;
    strUTF16.GetBufferSetLength(cbUTF8);
    WCHAR * pszUTF16 = new WCHAR[cchUTF16];

    int result = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,
        0,
        pszTextUTF8,
        cbUTF8,
        pszUTF16,
        cchUTF16
        );
    ATLASSERT( result != 0 );
    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }
    strUTF16.Format(_T("%s"), pszUTF16);
    return strUTF16;
}
```

`pszTextUTF8` is htm file's content in UTF-8.
When htm file's volume is less than 500kb, this code works well.
but, when converting over 500kb htm file, (ex 648KB htm file that I have.)
`pszUTF16` has all content of file, but `strUTF16` is not. (about half)
I guess File open is not wrong.

In `strUTF16 m_pszData` has all content how to I get that? 
`strUTF16.Getbuffer();` dosen't work.

Comment: `CStringW strUTF16 = CA2W(pszTextUTF8, CP_UTF8)` is all you need. If it's still not working then show the part that's reading the file. When reading the UTF8 file, make sure you leave room for nul-terminator and you zero the last byte.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved my problem. It was just MS Visual Studio's Text visualizer efficiency problem. I exported as file CString content that I converted. Than the file has complete content! Once more thanks~

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: That's a straight-forward solution, that works without putting much thought into it. It does, however, produce an extra copy, and requires two times the memory of the final string. Since the code in question wants to construct a `CStringW` object, you could write directly into its buffer, and safe both the extra buffer as well as the copy operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question is stock full of bugs, somewhere in the order of 1 bug per 1-2 lines of code.

Here is a short summary:

```
_wsetlocale( LC_ALL, L"Korean" );
```

Changing a global setting in a conversion function is unexpected, and will break code calling that. It's not even necessary either; you aren't using the locale for the encoding conversion.

```
HRESULT hr = ::StringCbLengthA( pszTextUTF8, cchUTF8Max, &cchUTF8 );
```

This is passing the wrong `cchUTF8Max` value (according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647509.aspx)), and counts the number of **bytes** (vs. the number of characters, i.e. code units). Besides all that, you do not even need to know the number of code units, as you never use it (well, you are, but that is just another bug).

```
int cbUTF8 = static_cast<int>( cchUTF8 );
```

While that fixes the prefix (**c**ount of **b**ytes as opposed to **c**ount of **ch**aracters), it won't save you from using it later on for something that has an unrelated value.

```
strUTF16.GetBufferSetLength(cbUTF8);
```

This resizes the string object that should eventually hold the UTF-16 encoded characters. But it doesn't use the correct number of characters (the previous call to `MultiByteToWideChar` would have provided that value), but rather chooses a completely unrelated value: The number of **bytes** in the UTF-8 encoded source string.

But it doesn't just stop there, that line of code also throws away the pointer to the internal buffer, that was ready to be written to. Failure to call `ReleaseBuffer` is only a natural consequence, since you decided against reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/614k79sd.aspx).

```
WCHAR * pszUTF16 = new WCHAR[cchUTF16];
```

While not a bug in itself, it needlessly allocates another buffer (this time passing the correct size). You already allocated a buffer of the required size (albeit wrong) in the previous call to `GetBufferSetLength`. Just use that, that's what the member function is for.

```
strUTF16.Format(_T("%s"), pszUTF16);
```

That is probably *the* anti-pattern associated with the `printf` family of functions. It is the convoluted way to write [`CopyChars`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cka9es.aspx) (or [`Append`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99t9bs1b.aspx)).

Now that that's cleared up, here is the correct way to write that function (or at least one way to do it):

```
CStringW ConvertUTF8ToUTF16( __in const CHAR * pszTextUTF8 ) {
    // Allocate return value immediately, so that (N)RVO can be applied
    CStringW strUTF16;
    if ( (pszTextUTF8 == NULL) || (*pszTextUTF8 == '\0') ) {
        return strUTF16;
    }

    // Calculate the required destination buffer size
    int cchUTF16 = ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8,
                                          MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
                                          pszTextUTF8,
                                          -1,
                                          nullptr,
                                          0 );

    // Perform error checking
    if ( cchUTF16 == 0 ) {
        throw std::runtime_error( "MultiByteToWideChar failed." );
    }

    // Resize the output string size and use the pointer to the internal buffer
    wchar_t* const pszUTF16 = strUTF16.GetBufferSetLength( cchUTF16 );

    // Perform conversion (return value ignored, since we just checked for success)
    ::MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8,
                           MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS, // Use identical flags
                           pszTextUTF8,
                           -1,
                           pszUTF16,
                           cchUTF16 );

    // Perform required cleanup
    strUTF16.ReleaseBuffer();

    // Return converted string
    return strUTF16;
}
```